# Byte Variable occupies in Memory 4 Bytes in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I need to convert a structure to a `Byte Array`. This structure contains `Integer`, `Single` and one `Byte` value:

```
     Public Structure SendDriveParams
            Public Command_code As Integer
            Public Drive_source As Integer
            Public Duration As Single
            Public RotationDirection  As Byte
            Public ID_1 As Integer
            Public Value_1 As Single
            Public ID_2 As Integer
            Public Value_2 As Single
            Public ID_3 As Integer
            Public Value_3 As Single
            Public ID_4 As Integer
            Public Value_4 As Single
            Public ID_5 As Integer
            Public Value_5 As Single
            Public ID_6 As Integer
            Public Value_6 As Single
    End Structure
```

I am using Marshal function to copy the structure to `Byte array`:

```
        Dim p As SendDriveParams
        Dim Ptr As IntPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(p))
        Dim ByteArray(Marshal.SizeOf(p) - 1) As Byte
        Marshal.StructureToPtr(p, Ptr, False)
        Marshal.Copy(Ptr, ByteArray, 0, Marshal.SizeOf(p))
        Marshal.FreeHGlobal(Ptr)
```

Checking the size results always in 64, but should be 61 (because all `Integer` and `Single` have 4 bytes, only the variable "RotationDirection" has one byte.

By remarking the "Rotationdirection" variable, I found out that the `Byte` occupies in memory obviously also 4 bytes ....

How possible?

Comment: what about RotationDirection?

Comment: You need to change the packing size `<StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack:=1)>` And I would actually expect 68 bytes (or 136 in a 64-bit app), or 65 with packing, depending on the type of `RotationDirection`

Comment: Great, yes, that did it ! I assumed it has to do with compiler boundaries and didnt know that directive. So, problem solved, thanks !
P.S: the "direction" variable came from copy and paste mistake, now the correct struct is shown in the question. And yes, now its 61 byte long

Comment: It's mainly about efficiency; unaligned access (which is what will happen to everything after `RotationDirection` if the padding isn't included) is much slower than aligned access.  If you have control of the layout of the `Structure`, I'd recommend to sort elements by storage size with larger elements appearing first.